# Программа-транслятор

Tags: java

Есть ли у кого какие-то книги, статьи, исходники, где об этом ясно и понятно написано? Сам я студент, поэтому не судите строго) У нас преподают С++, но мне почему-то взбрело в голову написать ее на Java.

Comment: Что и во что транслировать хотите?

Comment: Вводим текст, далее по заранее вбитой азбуке он переводится в другой.

Comment: и в чем тут проблема? придумай алгоритм, напиши код =)

Comment: Беда заключается в том, что я не могу продумать момент, когда текст сравнивается с азбукой. Точнее как его реализовать.

Comment: а в чём проблема? составьте таблицу перевода символов (у вас же один в один, да?), и по ней преобразуйте все символы.

Comment: > Вводим текст, далее по заранее вбитой азбуке он переводится в другой.

то есть просто подстановка? так это на три строчки программа

Comment: так тут проблема не с языком, а с собственным мышлением. Называется лень

Comment: Вот кстати говоря вы не правы. Я разными способами пытался решить проблему: replace не помог, StringTokenizer тоже. Тем более я же не прошу вот именно написать за меня целую программу, а или подсказать как сделать, или помочь несколькими строчками кода.

Comment: @Omfis, способов можно придумать много (тем более, что конкретикой Вы нас не балуете). 

В Java посмотрите на документацию про Map.

Comment: Ну по поводу конкретики, так у меня есть набросок того, как программа должна работать шаг за шагом, но в силу того что тут собрались господа программисты наиболее высшего качества(квалификации) чем я, я решил не обременять их подобными размышлениями, ибо у каждого к этой задаче есть как свой подход так и решение)

Comment: + сделайте скидку, что я в Java(да и вообще в программировании) новичок)Поэтому мне немножко трудно воспринимать ваши советы и идеи.

Comment: задача не ясна :)

Comment: > replace не помог, 

Почему не помог? Как именно использовали? Не стесняйтесь, код - в студию.

Comment: @Omfis Вероятно не "по вбитой азбуке", а по чему-то другому. Посмотрите http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javacc

Comment: >> сделайте скидку, что я в Java(да и вообще в программировании) новичок)Поэтому мне немножко трудно воспринимать ваши советы и идеи.

У тебя интернет есть. Вся документация с примерами в лежит в открытом доступе. Чтобы научиться программировать, нужно начать программировать.

Comment: А что Вы хотите-то? Сдать зачёт или научиться? Или то и другое? Если сдать зачёт в зимнюю сессию, то учиться уже позно. А если учиться -- то "dragon book" и тому подобное чтиво. Более точно тут народ назовёт, если интересно. Или можно старые ответы посмотреть -- вопрос-то всплывает регулярно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задание не очень ясно, поэтому сложно сразу так посоветовать.
Для начала нужно знать сроки, а также собственно саму задачу.

> Вводим текст, далее по заранее вбитой
> азбуке он переводится в другой.

Между каждым символом одной грамматики и другой есть взаимно однозначное соответствие? Т.е. каждому конкретному символу из входной грамматики всегда соответсвует один символ из другой? Если да, то реализация совсем простая и тривиальная, часть алгоритма уже вам описал, к примеру, KryDos.

Или же при трансляции текущего символа выходной символ зависит от предыдущего? Если ситуация такова, то можно построить конечный автомат (автомат Мура например), это не так уж и сложно, материала по этому в интернете много, поэтому подробно расписывать не буду, тем более, что, возможно, у вас ситуация проще будет. Упрощенно говоря с каждым символом, подающимся на вход вы будете переходить в определенное состояние автомата, которое "ожидает", что на вход подадутся определенные другие символы (в случае если подается "неожидаемый" символ, то автоамт переходит в состояние ошибки и грубо говоря на этом работу можно и закончить). К примеру на вход может подаваться только символы из множества {a,b,c}, на выход - символы из множества {d, e, f}. Допустим вам нужно, чтобы первым символом обязательно был 'a' или 'b'. В случае если был введен символ 'a' вы ожидаете, что введут 'c' и выводите 'd', в случае если был введен символ 'b' - вы ожидаете, что введут 'b' (снова) и тогда на выход подаете 'f'. Составляется таблица переходов: сначала находимся в некотором начальном состоянии (initial для примера), затем, в случае если на вход подался символ 'a', то мы переходим в состояние a1, если символ 'b', то мы переходим в состояние b1 и т.д.

Для всех этих переходов по сути нужно построить эту самую таблицу переходов. Например у себя в тетради и\или в MS Excel\LibreOffice Calc и т.д.

Подозреваю, что скорее всего вам нужно реализовать какой-то 1 из двух вышеописанных случаев. А вообще в идеале, если захотите разобраться с этой темой посерьезнее, то можно как раз почитать книги, к примеру тот же "dragon book", которую уже посоветовали вам в комментариях (достаточно литературы на эту тему). Но большинство таких простых задач вроде ваших можно решить либо простыми тривиальными алгоритмами, конечными автоматами или рекурсивным спуском. В более сложных случаях (когда нужно составлять LL(k) грамматики и т.д.) - нужно писать автоматы со стековой памятью и\или использовать генераторы типа Ragel, Lemon.

Answer (score 2):

Ну вообще было бы правильно выложить свои попытки решения. А то так получается, что мы все за Вас делаем.

Решение в лоб(алгоритм).

Создать два массива. В одном русский алфавит, в другом - Ваш собственный. Строку которую нужно транслировать в другой алфавит разбиваем на массив символов. В цикле смотрим на каждый символ и позицию в которой он находится в русском алфавите. Заменяем его символом из вашего алфавита, который находится на той же позиции что и исходный символ в русском алфавите. Или можно обойтись одним ассоциативным массивом(HashMap который в java).

Надеюсь, понятно описал.

Answer (score 2):

Что вы понимаете под транслятором? Программу-словарь? Простой вариант два массива строк, сложнее - коллекция объектов с полем указывающим на язык, с полем для оригинального значения, с коллекцией ссылок на синонимы, с коллекцией ссылок на дословные переводы, а потом просто делать выборку из этой кучи. Если вы делаете интерпретатор языка, то теория компиляторов/интерпретаторов доступна свободно, есть довольно тонкая книга по жабе, где в конце маленький интерпретатор васика, название книги забыл